# QGIS 2.8 Ubuntu 14.04 installation issues. Terminal command attempts to install 2.10 regardless of repository

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu

I have switched to a new computer, and need to re-install QGIS 2.8. I imagine some database changes have happened since I last installed it, because now, even though I direct installation to the `http://qgis.org/debian-ltr` (2.8) repository, it still assumes that `sudo apt-get install qgis` is meant for 2.10. The 2.10 repository is `http://qgis.org/debian`. I have installed 2.8 many times before with this same method, so I'm pretty baffled as to what's going on.

Proof of my repository:

[image]

I run `sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis` and get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-qgis : Depends: python-qgis-common (= 1:2.8.3+20trusty) but 1:2.10.1+20trusty is to be installed
 qgis : Depends: qgis-providers (= 1:2.8.3+20trusty) but 1:2.10.1+20trusty is to be installed
 Depends: qgis-common (= 1:2.8.3+20trusty) but 1:2.10.1+20trusty is to be installed
```

I have the 2.8 repository set, but for some reason the `install qgis` command looks for the 2.10 repository instead. When I set the repository to `http://qgis.org/debian`, it goes ahead and installs 2.10. What is going on here?

Comment: what do you see if you type `apt-cache madison qgis`?

Comment: @RobSkelly 
 `qgis | 1:2.8.3+20trusty | http://qgis.org/debian-ltr/ trusty/main amd64 Packages`
`qgis | 2.0.1-2build2 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages`
`qgis | 2.0.1-2build2 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe Sources`
`qgis | 1:2.8.3+20trusty | http://qgis.org/debian-ltr/ trusty/main Sources`

Comment: See my answer bellow, if you are lucky like me you will not even need to do thing in order just run the 'autoremove' line ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this myself.

I installed Synaptic Package Manager with `sudo apt-get install synaptic`, then searched all packages with "qgis" in the name. I found around 10 packages on my computer that were taken from the 2.10 repo. I deleted all of them, leaving only the 2.8 ones left. Tried `sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis` again and it worked like a charm.

I guess all the `purge`, `autoremove` etc commands I tried didn't end up actually removing everything relevant to a new install.

Answer (score 1):

What are exactly the commands you tried to uninstall 2.10? I would have tied tried this

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove qgis
```

And then you must input this line to also remove all automatically installed dependencies

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then switched to qgis-ltr repo and perform the install

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install qgis
```

Should work, just tried on a VM.

Comment: I tried this and still got the `unmet dependencies` error shown in my initial post. `sudo apt-get install qgis` seems to be trying to install 2.10, even though I am pointing to the 2.8 repo. Very confused.

Comment: This can actually be caused by the way you installed it in the first place. If you initially specified something else than just qgis at first install, this 'something else' must be specified as well during at uninstall and wont be removed by autoremove. Or so i guess.

Comment: Also and to be more specific I don't think apt try to install 2.10. It's just that  he found more up-to-date dependencies than those needed by the main package. And in some of theses 2.10 dependencies there is a reference to 2.10 main package (which you removed). So the installer is stuck until you either remove all those out-of sync dependencies or you switch back to the "more up to date" repository. Normally auto-remove is here to help, but it all depend on how you installed in first place as i said in last comment.